# Show Category Image with Link in Magento

Tags: magento

On my Magento homepage, I'd like to include a link to a few categories, along with their respective Category images. Obviously, I could manually link to the images, but it seems like it would only make sense there is a way to automatically pull the Category image along with the link. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this method : http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getImageUrl

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Magento 1.4+, I'm pretty sure you can do through a widget if your homepage is edited through a CMS page.

Answer (score 0):

1. **load the category** you will like to display the url and images of and then use `"getImageUrl ($category)"` to get the image of that category.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post, but I came across this probem and found the link below solved the problem and worked a treat in Magento 1.6.2

:
[Pull in category thumnails in magento.](http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/getting-category-thumbnail-images-with-magento/)